# Grpc client-side streaming and writing to postgres sql database using entity framework in .Net 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, streaming, grpc

We have a .net core API which takes in a client stream. Like this in the .proto file:

> rpc StreamEntries (stream Dto) returns (DtoResponse);

Implemented using this client-side streaming example as inspiration:
https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/basics/

Simplified code example:

```
    public override async Task<StreamEntriesResponse> StreamEntries(IAsyncStreamReader<EntryGrpcDto> requestStream, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            while (await requestStream.MoveNext())
            {
                var entry = requestStream.Current;
    
                // WHAT TO DO HERE? This one simply calls AddAsync on the dbcontext 
                await _entryRepository.AddAsync(entry);
            }
                // Calls SaveAsync on dbcontext
                await _entryRepository.SaveAsync(domain);

            return new StreamEntriesResponse();
        }
```

So ideally what we would like to do here would be to continously add records to the postgres sql database while receiving them and not batch up results (as the point of streaming would be kind of gone). It might be millions of records.

When fetching data from EF they provide a nice way to retrieve it as an IAsyncenumerable which we could then send easily with grpc in a server-side streaming scenario. But I have not been able to find a good example on how to stream to the database or if it is even possible? (Not a strict requirement to use Entity framework).

So the question is, is calling DbContext..AddAsync for each streamed entry, and then calling SaveAsync after all entries are streamed a feasible solution? It can be millions of entries.

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: So the question is, is calling DbContext.<T>.AddAsync for each streamed entry, and then calling SaveAsync after all entries are streamed a feasible solution? It can be millions of entries.

Comment: Create two connection to the database.  One strictly for adding data and second for reading large records.  Each connection can be a different thread that can be run asynchronously.

Comment: I am receiving data from a client in a stream which I want to add to a database and preferabely keep memory usage low

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to the problem? I'm currently looking for exactly the same thing ..

Comment: @dan-kli Hey, no, unfortuneately not

Comment: Ah, dang. Thanks for the reply. Did you end up using another technology, like a streaming data base, or what did you do in the end?

Comment: In the end I went with a solution where I receive 50k entries, then add those to the database using bulkinsert in a new thread while at the same time keep on receiving entries until I received 50k more entries. Then I awaited the bulkinsert before rinsing and repeating. Having two threads, one receiving and one storing data achieving some degree of parallelism.